# Running Windows 7 64 bit, Windows 7 32 bit and Ubuntu Linux together

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, filesystems, operating-systems

I had a Desktop PC with Intel x86 i5-3330 64 bit processor along with Windows 7 32 bit and Ubuntu Linux 14.04 64 bit together on the same Hard Disk Drive with dual boot with GRUB as the bootloader, after 8 years of working like this, I saw that 64 bit operating systems were the norm and I had to test my compiled code on 64 bit Windows, also Microsoft stopped support for Windows 7 from January 2020. So I thought to migrate to Windows 10 64 bit.

But I still had a lot of stuff installed on my old Windows 7 32 bit OS and lot of settings which I didn't want to loose, hence I decided to add a new Hard Disk Drive, and on that I would have Windows 10 64 bit and Ubuntu Linux 14.04 32 bit (just so that I have one of each kind, both 32 bit and 64 bit variants of Windows and Linux). I told my computer vendor to add a new Hard Disk Drive and install Windows 10 64 bit and Ubuntu Linux 14.04 32 bit on it as dual boot with GRUB as bootloader while not touching the old Hard Disk Drive, I told him when I would need to boot with Windows 7, I would go into BIOS and make the old Hard Disk Drive as boot device and when I needed to boot through Windows 10 64 bit, I would again go into BIOS and make the new HDD as the boot device. He did everything, but did not test by booting with the old Hard Disk Drive. Now I have my Desktop PC back from him and when I make the old Hard Disk Drive as boot device, I am unable to boot through Windows 7 32 bit (However booting through Ubuntu Linux 14.04 64 bit is working fine). The vendor tells me that Windows 10 64 bit and Windows 7 32 cannot co-exist as there is some Hard Disk formatting mismatch. Is this true? And if it indeed is, then can I have Windows 7 64 bit and Windows 7 32 bit co-exist like this, I really want to retail that old hard disk as a lot of configurations are there in that which I don't want to loose.

Comment: Btw, the RAM need of the Linuxes does not grow so much with time. Ubuntu LTS versions (like 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, 20.04) are supported 5 years long, ubuntu 14.04 is not supported any more, just like Win7.

Comment: (I use oldie laptops with Linuxes so: 1. I improve their RAM to the max, mostly to 8GB 2. I run a 32-bit Linux on them. 3. Linux is tricky, even 32-bit kernels can see at most 64GB RAM (more clearly, it is a feature of the CPU, named PAE. Microsoft has just disabled it.)).